OnAction method not firing in SPFx ACE card
I've created a simple ACE card using VS Code which contains a TextInput field and a button in the CardView (Not the Cards Quick View). The idea is to open a URL using the value of the TextInput as a value in the URL parameters.
I have used the sample from Paolo Pialorsi (Piasys),
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-K67yZo0l9w
I'm using SPFx 1.18.2 and my CardView.TS file is as follows
import {
  BaseComponentsCardView,
  ComponentsCardViewParameters,
  BasicCardView,
  IActionArguments
} from '@microsoft/sp-adaptive-card-extension-base';
import * as strings from 'KnowledgeArticleSearchAdaptiveCardExtensionStrings';
import {
  KnowledgeArticleSearchAdaptiveCardExtensionProps,
  KnowledgeArticleSearchAdaptiveCardExtensionState,
  QUICK_VIEW_REGISTRY_ID
} from '../KnowledgeArticleSearchAdaptiveCardExtension';

export class CardView extends BaseComponentsCardView<
  KnowledgeArticleSearchAdaptiveCardExtensionProps,
  KnowledgeArticleSearchAdaptiveCardExtensionState,
  ComponentsCardViewParameters
> {
  public get cardViewParameters(): ComponentsCardViewParameters {
    return BasicCardView({
      cardBar: {
        componentName: 'cardBar',
        title: this.properties.title
      },
      header: {
        componentName: 'text',
        text: strings.PrimaryText
      },
      footer: {
        componentName: 'textInput',
        id: 'searchTerm',
        placeholder: strings.TextboxPlaceholder,
        button: { 
          icon: { 
            url : 'Send'
          }, 
          action: 
          { 
            type: 'Submit',
            parameters: {
               id: 'showResults',
               searchTerm: '${searchTerm}'
            },
            
          } 
        }
       
      }
    });
  }

  public onAction(action: IActionArguments): void {
    if (action.type === 'Submit' && action.id === 'showResults') {
      window.open('https://MySearchURL?logicalNames=&q=${action.data.searchTerm}', '_blank');
      }
  }
}

When I click on the search button in the ACE card the OnAction never seems to fire.
The issues happens in both the WorkBench edit mode and when deployed to a Viva Connections Dashboard in Microsoft Teams/SharePoint Online.
Any pointers greatly appreciated!
Regards
Rob Ireland
